# Return list as json using jersey2.1 rest server giving errors?

Tags: java, rest, weblogic, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

I have deployed my jersey2.1 web service war file into weblogic12.2.1.3.0 and this was working fine with weblogic12.1.3.

And also I have configured in my web.xml servlet-class like below .

**com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.servletcontainer**

then why I am getting  below error in weblogic12.2.1.3.0.

**org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor**

I've tried everything... can't figure out why I'm getting below exception.
Do any of you have any suggestions?

**Error: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor**

**MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,type= class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList**

Comment: It's only happening for lists? Can you show the resource method?

Comment: No it's happening for objects when I am return objects getting this error.

Comment: Do you have a JSON provider? I don't use WebLogic, but if it already has a provider, maybe the one it uses requires your model classes to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. I don't know, I'm just guessing. You haven't really given us much information to go off of.